# Is $f(z) = z^{2}$ an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $f(z) = z^{2}$.  I claim $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space. First $\operatorname{ker}(f) = 0$ and since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed then for all $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$, $\sqrt{z}$ exists and so $f$ is surjective.

Comment: It is not even a bijection.

Comment: The kernel being zero implies injectivity if we have a *linear* map, but $z^2$ is far from being linear. You are overcomplicating this: $f(-1) = f(1) = 1$ so we do not get injectivity.

Comment: Moreover, $\sqrt{z}$ does not even exist without having to choose branch cuts and the like. Even if this worked, the 'proof' would require far more checking than you are claiming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $f(-z)=f(z) \ne -f(z)$ for $z \ne 0$. This shows that $f$ is neither injective nor linear.